# Объясните пожалуйста работу поведение this. Что в итоге выведет alert и почему?

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";

var user = {
  sayHi: function() {
    alert(this);
  }
};

(user.sayBye = user.sayHi)();
```

Answer (score 1):

А сами выполнить не пробовали?

Вернёт `undefined`.
Присвоение вернёт функцию, а выполнение метода вне объекта приведёт к дефолтному для функций `this`: `window` в обычном режиме, `undefined` в строгом.

И да, добавится ещё один метод, `sayBye`.

Comment: Блин, все-равно не совсем понимаю. Вот если сделать так в конце: user.sayBye = user.sayHi;
user.sayBye();

Comment: ТО и результат другой. почему, не ясно

Comment: Сори. разобрался. Спасибо)))

Comment: Присвоение возвращает функцию, **без** контекста родительского объекта. А если вызываешь `obj.method()`, то объект в контексте есть, `this` на месте.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Спасибо тут выражают в плюсах и, если решилось, примите ответ (галочка слева от ответа).